# python - New column based on comparison with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes.  I'd like to create a new column in one based on comparing it to another.

I'm new to Python, but here's my solution in R, which works but is horrific and slow.  I'd like to find a faster method, and I've been trying desperately to learn to use `pandas` since it seems like a good method.

Mapfile (has ~800,000 rows)

```
Name    Chr   Position
S1      1      3000
S2      1      6000
S3      1      1000
```

Armsfile (has 39 rows)

```
Chr    Arm    Start   End
1      p      0       5000
1      q      5001    10000
```

R Script:

```
for (line in 1:nrow(mapfile)){
      mapfile$Arm[line] <- Armsfile$Arm[mapfile$Chr[line] == Armsfile$Chr &  mapfile$Position[line] > Armsfile$Start &  mapfile$Position[line] < Armsfile$End]
      }
```

Output Table:

```
Name   Chr   Position   Arm
S1      1     3000      p
S2      1     6000      q
S3      1     1000      p
```

In words:
I want each line to look up the location ( 1) find the right `Chr`, 2) find the line where the `START < POSITION < END`), then get the `ARM` information and place it in a new column.

I tried just reformatting my R script for Python, but couldn't get the syntax right.  I also tried using `merge` for `pandas`, but couldn't find a way to do mathematical comparisons.

For completeness, here are my bad attempts just mentioned:

```
for line in 1:mapfile.shape[0]:
      mapfile$Arm[line] = Armsfile$Arm[   mapfile$Chr[line] == Armsfile$Chr &&  mapfile$Position[line] > Armsfile$Start &&  mapfile$Position[line] < Armsfile$End]
```

and

```
df = pd.merge(mapfile, Armsfile, on=['Chr', mapfile.Position > Armsfile.Start, mapfile.Position < Armsfile.End])
```

**Edit: Another possible way to think about it**

I've been working on another possibility in R that perhaps could translate somehow to Python.  Here's the R code:

```
mapfile <- data.frame(Name = c("S1", "S2", "S3"), Chr = 1, Position = c(3000, 6000, 1000), key = "Chr")
Chr.Arms <- data.frame(Chr = 1, Arm = c("p", "q"), Start = c(0, 5001), End = c(5000, 10000), key = "Chr")
mapfile$Arm <- c("N")
> mapfile
   Name Chr Position Arm
1:   S1   1     3000   N
2:   S2   1     6000   N
3:   S3   1     1000   N

for(i in 1:nrow(Chr.Arms)){
   cur.row <- Chr.Arms[i,]
   mapfile$Arm[mapfile$Chr == cur.row$Chr & mapfile$Position >= cur.row$Start & mapfile$Position <= cur.row$End] <- Chr.Arms$Arm
   }

> mapfile
   Name Chr Position Arm
1:   S1   1     3000   p
2:   S2   1     6000   p
3:   S3   1     1000   q
```

But again, with such large data, I'd like to be able to do something similar in Python.  I haven't yet found the solution.

Comment: You could take the Cartesian product and then filter it down.  Curious as to whether someone has a better solution than this.  Another possibility would be to use 'apply'.  You'd write a function that input Position and output Arm.  But you should avoid apply where possible because it's slower than vectorised approaches.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the rows would need to be in order.....I would have many rows that would be assigned p or q.  And they are not necessarily in order.  I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the intervals in Armsfile? Are they constant size? Are they non-intersecting?

Comment: The cartesian product approach is the one more fully fleshed out in Jared s answer. It doesn't require sorting.  It'd probably be ok memory wise with the size of your data but if it were much bigger then it's not a good general approach

Comment: Another thought : google for 'pandas binning data'  - there seem to be a number of general solutions to this problem...

Comment: Binning data seems like it may work, although I have to set different bins for each Chr (1:22).  I'll post the solution if I can get it to work and it quickens things (and no one else has posted an answer)

Comment: Might it be possible to enumerate all possible values in the arms file rather than it just having ranges,  and then use it as a look up?

Comment: That's sort of what I've been working on in R since I haven't found an elegant Python solution yet...but I don't know how to implement something like that in Python.  I'll post the R in the question.

Comment: If you can post a link to a csv of the two files I'll have a go if you like - a gist, or pastebin?  Whether it work depends on what the whole of these files look like (i.e. it's definitely possible with the excerpts you provided but i'm less sure it's possible with the full files...)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have many 800K rows of data, I don't know how optimal this is but could you:

1. merge
2. use `loc` to filter down the merged `dataframe`?

---

```
df = Mapfile.merge(Armsfile)
df.loc[(df['Position'] > df['Start']) & (df['Position'] <= df['End'])].drop(['Start', 'End'], axis=1)
```

Note: I wasn't sure how to handle the `Armsfile` `Chr` because your `Mapfile` and `Armsfile` both had `Chr` of 1 in your example.

Comment: The Chr column needs to add up, so I assume I could use `df = Mapfile.merge(Armsfile, on=['Chr'])`??  The R script I wrote took several hours to complete.  And this 800k is one of my smaller ones that I need to do this on.  My largest dataset I'll need is 38 million lines, so that's why I'm really concerned with efficiency.

Comment: Understandable. My understanding about [Merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) `on=` parameter is that if `left_index` and `right_index` equals `False`, and `on=None`, the intersection will be detected automatically - in this case by `Chr` since it's in both `Armsfile` and `Mapfile`. This means you may not need to use the `on=` parameter.  I don't think it would hurt if you did.  I end up with the same result regardless.